# How do you refer to "the company of another person" as in companionship, not a business

Tags: meaning

If I try to search this anywhere, I can only find 会社。

I want to say "you have nothing, but the company of another person"

Comment: "I enjoy her company." 「彼女と一緒にいると楽しい」

Comment: I think the word you are looking for is [付き合い](https://dictionary.goo.ne.jp/thsrs/8459/meaning/m0u/). (Yes, I should probably post this as an answer and elaborate on it, but I don't have time right now.)